# Mass-assign attributes fails in nested form. Silent error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-attributes

There are several questions here that [cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525962/how-do-i-make-nested-attributes-work-in-rails3) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579279/accepts-nested-attributes-for-causing-sqlexception) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381897/accepts-nested-attributes-not-saving-any-changes), I know. I am new to programming and rails, so please bear with me. My goal is to collect `n` tag objects and display them in my show and index actions.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to both guys who answered. Each suggestion nudged me in the right direction. I am able to get the rake task to create posts by passing in an empty array to initialize the `tags` object. However tags are still not created. On further inspection I get the following SQL exception:

```
irb(main):002:0> u.posts.build(title: "a new day", tags: "jump")
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tags
(1.7ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."title" = 'a new day' LIMIT 1
(0.5ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Post id: nil, title: "a new day", description: nil, content: nil, user_id: 1,    created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My set up is as follows:

`Tag` Model

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :post

end
```

`Post` Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :tags, autosave: true
attr_accessible :title, :description, :content, :tags_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attrs| attrs.all? {|key, value| value.blank?}}
#add n number of form fields to capture tags in each article.
   def with_blank_tags(n = 3)
     n.times do
       tags.build
     end
     self
    end
end
```

'View' code

```
<%= form_for(@post.with_blank_tags) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.fields_for(:tags) do |tags| %>
   <%= unless tags.object.new_record? tags.check_box('_destroy') + tags.label('_destroy', 'Remove Tag') end%>
   <%= tags.label :tags, "Add a Tag"%>
   <%= tags.text_field :tags %>
  <%end%>   
</div>
<%end%>
```

'Controller' code

```
def new
 @post = @user.posts.build
end

def create
 @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save?
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    else
     format.html { render action: :new }
    end
   end
end
```

My rake task:

```
namespace :db do
desc "Fill database with sample data"
task :posts => :environment do
 Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
  make_users
  make_posts
 end
end

def make_users
 puts "making users..."
  5.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  password = "foo"
  email = "example-#{n+1}@example.com"
    @user=User.create!(
                codename: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                password_confirmation: password)
end
 end

def make_posts
 puts "making posts..."
User.all(:limit => 3).each do |user|
  10.times do
    content = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(3)
    description = Faker::Lorem.words(10)
    title = Faker::Lorem.words(4)
    tag = []
    post = user.posts.create!(title: title, description: description, content: content, tags_attributes: tag)
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this matters. But a lot of the other questions and examples ive seen on the web so far have had the accepts nested attributes call before the attr_accessible call. Maybe it needs to be defined before making #{name}_attributes white listed?

Comment: @agmcleod I placed the call in the order you suggested and received the same exception.

Comment: @agmcleod I came across a solution in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792622/what-does-this-rake-dbseed-error-mean) that suggests renaming the model. I wonder if the name Tag for a model is not acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. After rdocs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), in order to set your nested attribute you pass an array of hashes to the *_attributes. This removes the error I described above and sets the object id `tags_id`.

All I had to do was remove this line:

```
tag = []
post = user.posts.create!(title: title, description: description, content: content, tags_attributes: tag)
```

and replace it with this inside of my rake task:

```
tag = Faker::Lorem.words(1) # create a tag
post = user.posts.create!(tags_attributes: [tags: tags])
```

Now when I do something like `Tag.all` from my console I see:

```
[#<Tag id: 1, post_id: 1, tags: "---\n- adipisci\n", created_at: "2012-01-12 06:31:13", updated_at: "2012-01-12 06:31:13">,
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare some attributes as `attr_accessible` on a model in rails, then all other attributes are automatically set as `attr_protected`.  Looks to me like your problem may be stemming from the fact that you're trying to create a post and assign the `tags` attribute simultaneously.  Try adding `:tags` to the list of `attr_accessible` attributes in your `Post` model and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you @Batkins. I made the change and received the following error  in the console `rake aborted!
Tag(#38643420) expected, got String(#18449760)`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can build a post through a user relationship, and create a tag through the post relationship all in one line.  As in, `@post = @user.posts.build(tags: Tag.new)` may need to be split up into `@post = @user.posts.build` and then a new line with `@post.tags.build`.  That's just a guess.

Comment: Well at any rate it looks like my answer solved the problem where you were getting `can't mass-assign protected attributes` problem, which was the problem you had when you asked the question, so would you accept my answer as being correct?  You could pose the new error as a separate question.

Comment: I agree. if you don't mind I will assign the proper solution to the problem I posted.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I gave the proper solution to the original problem posted.

Comment: Please post your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828395/mass-assign-attributes-fails-in-nested-form-where-is-the-error) and I will accept it.

Comment: it turns out the mass-assignment error was just next up. Thank you for your effort. Going to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

In the #create on your controller, don't you want to be calling `@post.save` ? You do not need the  second .tags method either. Just a simple:

```
def create
  @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

Comment: It was correct in my codebase but not in this post. Same error occurring.

Comment: Following your suggestions and removing the `tags` from the attr_accessible call allows the sample data to be generated. Thank you.

Comment: After inspecting a `post` object in my console it appears that the tag object did not save. any ideas?

Comment: still empty. I added my rake task to complete the picture.

Comment: in a rake task you have to name it "tags_attributes"